# Sometimes Getting Incorrectly Generated Passwords

Tags: bash

I am using the following function to generate passwords:

```
genpasswd() {
  local l=$1
  [[ "$l" == "" ]] && l=15
  echo $(tr -dc "[:print:]" < /dev/urandom | head -c ${l})
}
```

This works almost all of the time; however, every now and then I get a password with a strange character or a password that is not the correct length. This can be demonstrated by running the following command:

```
COUNTER=0; while [ $COUNTER -lt 1000000 ]; do; pass=$(genpasswd); if [ ${#pass} -ne 15 ]; then; echo $pass; fi; done
```

It generated the following output for me for instance (I cut it off after a little while):

```
G/bteEpm
U^e^!7oT\hGC3)
S7Dcpio1GlQTM
CYOyMMA
$Ze^li
&EKl}'o]u7[]T5
i|y9@6P7?
I9)y
3HIZ"0S%65X[md
sIiWTHk2&0>k}e
O
iy3WET^1q+|(
Mh'6A:Z^;lP-x`
e
htQ%sGl4LWl2
:hhHeoG(Hd%(ct
lp?[Qw'~Z994iy
{SK"
giUI|L4Vz
d0G]+?x|
        baR
G0B[sqBr,sXiZ:
o&vi[D4HA/uRwg
^(a(UX40ubapQJ
wh6ZW)]"=\O_:n
pNUapE`t$k@b1K
A`6^)?|'
Xt$vA
M8t!#T(J2@
a
B]FazJBd6#2iY1
\7d-V$O+LQcn8@
6<f-\%GNXKNqU'
W}kY{,N&WU[Gc1
]GPrZn678Vy0c`
O@"o#0zQh^g.('
1Sy).
]5J#rA-S
nk9g
(0{z][,M[
P5vB9[5A1C#h`o
_PC+r1S9$hg%CS
T1p-M6iB9t`-_F
o8RR-V`(|&M@'8
OD-k=SMu}7N$#C
2@qus0),FNMhIq
z$mzQ>kW9;HZ}!
dn@KA
Q>6,35gu
2Uj]_&|TbG"ZNo
1:U)JFjou{SaR9
vq}O}IV}s9:cT@
*[%(1U:lbB.NR!
w{znznAf.'6@UC
6_1m/E0\XaHv`V
q3#yuQ0mY+\pF&
%=,l^vE+]')[gO
AT4cMA5{p<Q'M:
xC9jR'I'Vx=LFQ
+RyVQ6%j{nTz>u
=oVpz+Uw+#CV?Q
KRkH
s'sl$Bk:$
f[}2*>^|q_5_|)
u>l}%*I.O/1ea!
&+joM"k-0`Dz-u
t
3
@`H[/?X!]A
[(p)*,4P>OB.K]
PVv}w@/RAw4#$M
x.S[GjK2Y?-O|A
f5NoAZ\ofTrkg&
DYcij8)]d3?<Yi
F+d@pK>kc7KtoP
7@EPtAe$QSw#%s
[P*I.k?DdM}lZc
jkuL37]OGu`CW\
q.c2%qm"'7r(se
vFwGk5;pj08>5
.DXE
    lHhj%8.~
W<}wun]hMym%/<
!}7<JpP`,-h~%^
9UW?L=sEvymmI^
4#w4/E|=}5bQpb
^C
```

Why is it doing this? I assume some sort of escape character issue or something but I can't figure it out. How can I fix it?

Comment: I would use `pwgen` for that

Comment: @hek2mgl Sounds good. Mind if I post an exact solution using the flags I want?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @hek2mgl I now have the following function which does not have the same problem:

```
genpasswd() {
  local len=$1
  [[ -z $len ]] && len=15
  pwgen -syN 1 "$len"
}
```

Comment: Good solution. Just a hint, avoid to name a variable `l`. It's hard to distinguish between a `1` (literal one) in most fonts. `len` would be a better variable name in this case. Furthermore, always quote your variables when you access them, the last line should be `pwgen -syN 1 "$len"`

Comment: @hek2mgl should I also quote `l` in the check?

Comment: It doesn't hurt. But basically when used in an extended(!) if `[[` it is safe to not quote the variable. This is because the `[[` is a builtin. Nowadays also `[` should be a builtin but originally it was an external command.

Comment: @hek2mgl Thanks for your help!